# Adding memory allocation to a C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management, allocation

**Question**

What is the most efficient way to add memory allocation to an already declared variable?

For example:

```
int n=3;
int m = 4;
int * p;
p = new int[n];
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) {/*function that stores values in p*/}
```

From there, how to get to:

```
p = new int[n+m];
```

**By copying**

I've thought about making a new variable (y for example) with the required memory allocation (n+m) and copy the value of p to it and then copy y to p. Is that the most efficient way to do this ?

Example:

```
int * y;
y = new int[n + m];
for(int i = 0; i < n;i++) {y[i] = p[i];}
p = y;
delete [] y;
```

**Related question:**

Is there a purpose for memory allocation without an array?

Example:

```
int * p;
p = new int;
```

What would require this method instead of declaring `int p`?

Comment: Why on earth did you `delete [] y;` after assigning it?

Comment: The most efficient way is to use `std::vector`, where "efficient" is about both computing and programmer effort.

Comment: Why would I keep both y and p if I only needed the final result ?

Comment: Because y and p are both pointing to the same space in memory. If you delete y, you also delete p. You need to allocate a whole new array for p, copy the contents of the array at y to the array at p, and then you can safely delete y. but there isn't much need for this. so long as p is still pointing at y's memory, y can go the way of the dodo and later you can delete p. the real problem is in deleting p's memory before you lose the pointer to it by copying y over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that the most efficient way to do this ?

No, this is no good because you freed what to use and caused memory leak by not freeing what will be no longer used. At least it should be

```
int * y;
y = new int[n + m];
for(int i = 0; i < n;i++) {y[i] = p[i];}
delete [] p;
p = y;
```

There may be more efficient method, depending on the usage. For example, linked list may be more efficient if you don't need randam access for elements.

Comment: So instead of using p, I should just delete p and use y from there ?
(there is a mistake on the last line of your code)

Comment: @JoGooD No error was found in [my test](https://ideone.com/srNmWL). Please tell me the mistake you found. Which of `p` or `y` should be used may depend what you want, but I guess typically using `p` is better because it may be declared for larger scope.

Comment: `delete [] p;`
    `p = y;`
    `p` is deleted then `y` is assigned to `p`

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is `std::vector`.  You can use this like an array that you can resize dynamically.

```
int n=3;
int m = 4;
std::vector<int> p(n);
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) { ... }
```

then later

```
p.resize(n+m);
```

The memory will also freed automatically when `p` goes out of scope.